# Using two Connection Objects in a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I am working on a legacy application in which jsp files are used for creating and closing connection, I do not have rights to change or view the connection files.
Everything works fine until there are multiple Connection files are used in a single file, in that case the connection object created in the first file is always used, and the connection object from second file is simply ignored. which gives a SQLCODE=-204 error which is for table not found.

files are added like

```
<%@ include file="connection1.jsp"%>
//Code requiring connection1.jsp goes here
<%@ include file="disconnect1.jsp"%>
<%@ include file="connection2.jsp"%>
//Code requiring connection2.jsp goes here
//The exception with SQLCODE=-204 occurs here
<%@ include file="disconnect2.jsp"%>
```

I am giving the complete stack trace of error for reference

```
Dec 16, 2014 6:33:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=CPSDUSER.CLR_SOE_LIN_ITM_SMRY, DRIVER=3.53.95
    at org.apache.taglibs.jdbc.resultset.MultipleResultSetTag.doStartTag(MultipleResultSetTag.java:41)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.choosecealer_jsp._jspService(choosecealer_jsp.java:1338)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:627)
    at tags.templates.GetTag.doStartTag(GetTag.java:46)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.cnirmaintemplate_jsp._jspx_meth_template_005fget_005f2(cnirmaintemplate_jsp.java:176)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.cnirmaintemplate_jsp._jspService(cnirmaintemplate_jsp.java:96)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:627)
    at tags.templates.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:25)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:1870)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Dec 16, 2014 6:33:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/choosecealerrgn.jsp at line 18

15:         || menuitem.equals("clrlylbonus")
16:
17:         || menuitem.equals("clraoi")
18:
19:         || menuitem.equals("overviewwizard")
20:
21:         || menuitem.equals("summarywizard")


Stacktrace:
    at tags.templates.GetTag.doStartTag(GetTag.java:48)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.cnirmaintemplate_jsp._jspx_meth_template_005fget_005f2(cnirmaintemplate_jsp.java:176)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.cnirmaintemplate_jsp._jspService(cnirmaintemplate_jsp.java:96)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:627)
    at tags.templates.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:25)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:1870)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Dec 16, 2014 6:33:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/choosecealerrgn.jsp at line 18

15:         || menuitem.equals("clrlylbonus")
16:
17:         || menuitem.equals("clraoi")
18:
19:         || menuitem.equals("overviewwizard")
20:
21:         || menuitem.equals("summarywizard")


Stacktrace:
    at tags.templates.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:27)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:1870)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: It seems that somehow the same STATEMENT is getting execute more than one time. Check for RESULTSET object.

Comment: The trace is of a single statement and the resultsets are unique @rishi prakash

Comment: Can you share the code where statement executes, if possible.

Comment: I am not at liberty to share the code, if i was i would have shared it in the question

Comment: OK, are you using something like <c:forEach items> in your code?

Comment: No, there are custom tags. They work perfectly, they are in use in other applications as well, and they are all working well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67086/discussion-between-rishi-prakash-and-ankur-kumawat).

Comment: use of `connection pooling` is strongly recomended and use the business logic in `servlets` calling via ajax

Comment: I know what is recommended but as i stated in my question i cannot modify connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution earlier, but couldn't get here.
It was that, the tags were modified as per the needs, the connection was not being reinitialized there, that's why the same connection object was used.
When it was reinitialized it worked.